# Multistep form makes same submissions

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, forms

I created a Ctools Multistep form. Its working fine. But when a user opens this multistep form in two tabs and fill the form fields simultaneously and submits it, **both the submitted forms have same values for all the fields. Means both the submissions have same data**.

When I have submitted this form in different browsers simultaneously, then both submissions have their own data.

I followed this tutorial to make Ctools Multistep form : http://www.xenyomedia.com/content/4-steps-form-multistep-form-ctools

I think, the problem is with **$object_id = 'ctools_multistep';**, because its same for both the forms in different tabs. Thats why it creates the same submissions for both forms.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Whats the requirement? Why user trying to submit same form two times using different browser tabs?

Comment: Hi Arun, client raised the bug for it. And for clarification, when user submit forms using two tabs of same browser, then this problem occure.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Howmany google accounts we can login from a single browser?

If you want to check concurrent user scenario use different browser or at-least try with normal and private browsing(incognito) mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have picked up correctly, the root cause for this issue is the object_id used by ctools multistep form, which is being generated per session. And for different tabs in a browser, we have the same session. So basically we need to figure out a way to get different object_id for each tab. This can be done in two ways:
1. Modify session mechanism to have a different session per tab. (Difficult)
2. Use query_parameters to handle two different requests. (For eg: time as id)

So, using 2nd way to solve our the problem:
Get object_id dynamically.

```
$object_id = _module_get_object_id();
```

Ensure if id exists in URL, else return newly generated id.

```
function _module_get_object_id() {
  $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  if (isset($params['id'])) {
    return $params['id'];
  }
  else {
    $params['id'] = time();
    return $params['id'];
  }
}
```

and most **important step**, for **adding id in URL as query parameter** we need to add following code in the ctools_multistep_wizard_next function:

```
drupal_goto($form_state['redirect'][0], array('query' => array('id' => $form_state['object_id'])));
```

Reference: http://savaslabs.com/2015/06/23/implementing-ctools-multi-step-form-block.html